# List all content not matching criteria in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I'd like to list all the pages that ***do not*** have a type of `featured`. If I want only the featured pages, I would use the following:

```
{{ range ( where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "featured" ) }}
...
{{ end }}
```

What's the opposite of that? I know I can list all the pages and then put an `if` inside of the range, but I'm thinking there must be a way to do it in the `range` expression itself.

Answer (score 1):

OK...figured this out. The operator needed to be in quotation marks, so this works:

```
{{ range ( where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "!=" "featured" ) }}
...
{{ end }}
```

I had tried using the operator without the quotation marks and it kept throwing an error.